# How to group column value in different column and display it in different column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

I have a column named company and company response to customer. I need to select the company and company response to customer that has three value 'Closed', 'Closed with explanation', and 'Closed with non-monetary relief'.

I have to display it into 4 columns company, 'Closed with explanation' with 'Closed' value, 'Closed with explanation' with 'Closed with explanation' value, 'Closed with explanation' with 'Closed with non-monetary relief' value. This is what I want

[image]

Does anyone know what command I need to use to display it into 4 different columns?

This is my current syntax. It's already group by company but I haven't display it into different column

```
select company, count(`Company Response to Consumer`)
from consumercomplaints
where `Company Response to Consumer` in ('Closed', 'Closed with explanation', 'Closed with non-monetary relief')
group by company
```

This is the current output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a case expression here to create your columns

```sql
select 
    company, 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN `Company Response to Consumer`='Closed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as `Closed`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN `Company Response to Consumer`='Closed with explanation' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as `Closed with explanation`,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN `Company Response to Consumer`='Closed with non-monetary relief' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as `Closed with non-monetary relief`
from consumercomplaints
where `Company Response to Consumer` in ('Closed', 'Closed with explanation', 'Closed with non-monetary relief')
group by company
```

NB. The where clause is optional here as the case expression provides a `0/1` value which when summed counts the number of occurrences in the dataset.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You do want conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, this is most simply handled by using `sum(<boolean expression>)`:

```
select company,
       sum(`Company Response to Consumer` = 'Closed') as num_closed,
       sum(`Company Response to Consumer` = 'Closed with explanation') as num_closed_with_explanation,
       sum(`Company Response to Consumer` = 'Closed with non-monetary relief') as num_closed_with_nonmonetary_relief
from consumercomplaints
where `Company Response to Consumer` in ('Closed', 'Closed with explanation', 'Closed with non-monetary relief')
group by company;
```